# Keytool gives me ? marks in CMD

Tags: java, keytool

So I have been trying to acquire an keystore, by using the Keytool in Java JDK-17

but i keep on getting ? marks instead of the real text
I searched up online and was able to answer the questions but it does not let me end after i say
yes to the "are the information correct"(or something like that) any body know a solution?[This is what is looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v84o5.png)

Comment: Are the characters that show up as `?` simply an unsupported character set (from a foreign language etc)?

Comment: Use `keytool >x.txt` and with Notepad++ or such you might find out it's encoding. The cmd cannot convert the key tool's output to its own encoding.